# How to calculate True Positive (TP) in deep learning object detection?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

[Question1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZufK.png)

Question 1: suppose that box a and Box B are predicted by the model, and the green box is the real box. The IOU of box a and Box B and the real box are greater than the threshold. Both a and B are processed by NMS. When calculating TP, do box a and Box B count one TP or two TP?

[Question2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dO6rw.png)

Question 2: the green box is the real box, the black box is the prediction box, and the IOU of the prediction box and the two real boxes are greater than the threshold. When calculating TP, is this one TP or two TP?

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: Both boxes are true positives as both are greater than the IOU threshold. There would be 2 TP's in this case

Question 2: Any predicted box can only match with one particular ground-truth box.  If there are multiple ground-truths, the best match (greater IoU) is always selected. In your case, let's call the 2 green real boxes (ground-truths) `box A` and `box B`, and the predicted black box as `box_pred`. Let's say `box A` has an IOU of 0.6 with `box_pred` and `box B` has an IOU of 0.5 with `box_pred`. In this case, `box_pred` will be considered as the only one TP, since it matches with `box A` with higher IOU.

[Link](https://towardsdatascience.com/confusion-matrix-in-object-detection-with-tensorflow-b9640a927285) for further reference

Answer (score 0):

**Q1:** Only the one with larger confidence score is taken as TP, the other is FP. (see [VOC paper](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/ckiw/postscript/ijcv_voc09.pdf) Page12 the upper-left corner)

**Q2:** It depends. Assuming something more crazy, the pred1 overlapped with GT-A(iou = 0.9) and GT-B(iou = 0.5 > threshold), usually we believe it's the TP pred of GT-A, **HOWEVER**, when there's pred2 also overlap with GT-A(iou > threshold but may be less than 0.9), then what the algorithm do?

The confidence score will decide who's the TP of GT-A, i.e.
(1) Confidence score of pred1, in abbrev. cs_pred2 > cs_pred1, 
--> TP of GT-A is pred2, and TP of GT-B is left to pred1 when there's no more pred overlapping with GT-B & having confidence score > cs_pred1.
(2) cs_pred2 < cs_pred1, 
--> TP of GT-A is pred1. Because in this case the assignment of pred1 is first considered by program, and the program saw that apprently the IoU(pred1, GT-A) >> IoU(pred1, GT-B), so the pred1 should be the TP corresponding to GT-A.

---

This may be confusing. If you're still reading, I'd say **logically**,

when dealing with AP, the deciding of T/F-P, T/F-N can be summarized into the following 3 steps,

(1) by confidence score of each predidctions, desciding if the pred is Positive / Negative.
(2) by iou(pred, gt), deciding if a Postive pred is True / False.
(3) if for a gt object, multiple Positive preds exists, keep the one with the highest confidence score as True, and turned all the others, if not being a candidate to other gt objects, just to False.